# Add compiler to PATH environment variable

Tags: java, variables, path, environment

I have already installed the JDK for java which i believe has the compiler and everything i need. 
Now I installed Netbeans and it is telling me that it cannot find the compiler, and to set my environment variable.

I have had my hard drive replaced i don't know if thats why I'm having trouble 
variable value is

```
%SystemRoot%\system32; %SystemRoot%; %SystemRoot%\System32\Wbem; 
%SYSTEMROOT%\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\
```

I tried to add this directly after.

```
;C:Program\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_71\bin
```

as well as

```
;%ProgramFiles%\Java\jdk1.7.0_71\bin
```

It doesn't work. Please help, any suggestions .

Comment: Your first path says "C: **Program** \Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_71\bin". Is the "Program" part intentional? It shouldn't be there.

Comment: Your first attempt seems to have a rogue `Program` in it. Have you tried just `c:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_71\bin`?

Comment: I typed it as so. c:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_71\bin                  I must have accidentally put a Program. I have already added JAVA_HOME as directed below. Still not working

Answer (score 0):

Set the path...
Find JDK Installation Directory

First you need to know the installation path for the Java Development Kit.

Open the default installation path for the Java Development Kit

C:\Program Files\Java

There should be a subdirectory like

C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.6.0_10

Set the JAVA_HOME Variable

Once you have the JDK installation path:

```
Right-click the My Computer icon on
your desktop and select Properties.
Click the Advanced tab. Click the
Environment Variables button. Under System Variables, click New.
Enter the variable name as JAVA_HOME.
Enter the variable value as the installation path for the Java Development Kit.
Click OK.
Click Apply Changes.
```

Restart pc

Read more here http://www.robertsindall.co.uk/blog/setting-java-home-variable-in-windows/

Answer (score 0):

You have to set your JAVA_HOME to your jdk (something like that C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_71) and add to te Path the bin folder of the jdk (someting like C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_71\bin)

Answer (score -1):

1. declare JAVA_HOME = C:Program\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_71\
2. add bin in path with PATH = %PATH%;%JAVA_HOME%\bin

try javac or java

Comment: This doesn't solve the OP's problem at all. You just copied what the OP said he or she did in the question.